# Swift TableView Tab sends wrong Index while edit sends the correct one

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue, swipe, tap

When I tap on the Cell on my tableview it sends the wrong index but when I use a swipe left it sends the correct index. It seems to fail on the odd index taps. Sorry about the Var names It means Assembled.

Here is the code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath AssIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let assCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(assCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: AssIndexPath) as! AssTableViewCell
    AssItemIndexPath = AssIndexPath.row
    let Ass = assDataArray[AssIndexPath.row]
    assCell.MainLabel.text = Ass.name

    assCell.selectionStyle = .None
 //   assCell.SubLabel2.text = ("Qty In Stock \(Ass.qtyInStock)")
    assCell.SubLabel.text = ("Sell Price $\(Ass.sellPrice)")


    return assCell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath AssIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    AssItemIndexPath = AssIndexPath.row
}

override  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath AssIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
{
    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Report" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, AssIndexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in

     AssItemIndexPath = AssIndexPath.row

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("report", sender: nil)



    })

    shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [shareAction]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I overwrite this method didSelectRowAtIndexPath when I need index of the selected row, I hope it helps.

See the following link where they explain about Managing Selections:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're overriding the correct function? If you just want something to happen on row selection override this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let index = indexPath.row
        let item = items[index]
        print("\(item.name)")
    }
```

In your UITableViewController

Comment: are there two differ actions reading the tap and reading the swipe?

Comment: can I turn off tap and still have swipe?

Comment: I'm not sure. Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH2-SW1 there's a section on TableViews